# Add function to search-suggestions (Savoy Theme, Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Im using the popular savoy theme, and looking for a way to add functions to the ajax search suggestion in savoy/woocommerce, is there a specific hook?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_color_attribute', 5 );
function display_color_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'pa_color';
        echo '<span class="attribute-color">' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

This adds color attributes to shop page.

Can i change "woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title" to another hook and get it to display it under title in the search suggestion tab?